# How can I iterate over Jason structure?

Tags: json, python-3.x, loops

I am trying to create a list to collect all the ids from a JSON file. 
To get one id I did: list= dict['files']['file'][0]['id']. I was wondering if I can do loop for it.

The Json Object is:

{'files':{'page': 1, 'pages': 123, 'perpage': 2, 'file': [{'id': '123', 'name': 'John'}, {'id': '234', 'name': 'Lee'}, {'id': '345', 'name': 'Josh'}, {'id': '456', 'name': 'mi'...}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxrSi.png)

Answer (score 0):

In python3 you can iterate over a dictionary like so:

```
for key, val in dic['file'][file].items():
    print(key, val['id'])
```